# groovy: convert a list of interface implementation to a map with compileStatic

Tags: list, groovy, compile-static

I am just a newer to groovy.

```
@Service
@CompileStatic
@Slf4j
class JourneyExecutionService {

    @Autowired
    List<DecisionEngineService> engineList;

    Map<String, DecisionEngineService> engineMap;
    void init(){
        engineMap = engineList.collectEntries {[it.getIndex(), it]}
        engineMap = engineList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(DecisionEngineService.getIndex, Functions.identity()))
    }
```

The compile shows both statements in the `init` function fail due to the error:

`Cannot assign 'Map<Object, Object>' to 'List<String, DecisionEngineService>'`
and `Cannot resolve symbol 'getIndex'`

The 2nd statement in a java stream style.

The interface interface is like

```
interface DecisionEngineService {

    String getIndex()
}
```

Can anyone helps fix the compileation issue?
Thanks

Comment: Should it not be `.collectEntries {[(it.getIndex()): it]}`? `DecisionEngineService.getIndex` is unknown syntax. `DecisionEngineService::getIndex` should work in groovy 3, or alternatively, use a corresponding closure

Comment: @ernest_k no, he's using the list on `collectEntries{}`

Comment: Its `DecisionEngineService::getIndex` in java and it will only work for Groovy>=3

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to cast the map explicitly:

```
Map<String, DecisionEngineService> engineMap;

void init(){
  engineMap = (Map<String, DecisionEngineService>)engineList.collectEntries {[it.index, it]}
}
```